# Qt creator Xbox one controller input

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gamepad

My issue is that I am trying to connect an Xbox one controller up to my pc for it to be understood and used by QT creator. I have looked around and have found the gamepad library. there are two example files for this library which is quick gamepad and simple gamepad. The Quick gamepad uses qml to "talk" to the controller and works but I can't seem to access the data to be used in the C++ files. On the other hand there is Simple game pad which uses C++ to access the data but it doesn't seem to want to connect to my controller.
My question is: is there anyway to connect to my controller and for the data to be used in C++?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your issue? DId you try to run those examples https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgamepad-examples.html ?

Comment: Please recheck this behavior again, try replugging the controller. What OS are you running? What kind of driver is installed for the controller? Do non-qt programs detect the controller correctly? Do you recieve any error messages? Is there anything odd in OS logs? What is your QT version? Are you sure you didn't accidentally forget to close one program before running the other?